# Parsing json in service worker getting undefined

Tags: javascript, json, service-worker

I'm trying to parse a json inside a service worker, but I'm not being able to do it.

This is the data i'm trying to parse in the push notification:

```
{"data": {"url": "www.google.com", "text": "teste", "icon": "http://example.com/abc.gif", "title": "title"}}
```

And this is my code:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {

  var payload = event.data.text();


  if ( payload.length > 0 ) {

        event.waitUntil(    
            fetch(payload, {
            method: 'get'
            })
            .then(function(response) { 
                console.log('response');
                console.log(response);
                return response.json(); 
            })
            .then(function(data) {
                console.log(data.text);
                console.log(data.title);
                self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
                  body: data.text,
                  icon: data.icon
                });
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('err');
            console.log(err);
            });

        );

  }
```

I'm getting data.text and data.icon as undefined.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse(payload) to parse the payload